# Call to lambda is ambiguous despite explicitly stating the return type

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, implicit-conversion, std-function

An overloaded function should take both functors in, given the type of the lambda is decidable ( castable to an `std::function` (please correct me if I'm wrong ).
The question is: Why is there a compile error below, despite the lambda type being explicitly defined? ( `[&]() -> Type {}` )

Please note, that for my current solution I need the capture-by-reference, 
that is why the code contains the logic for it.

The following example describes the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    
#include <functional>

void do_some(std::function<void(int)> thing) 
{
   thing(5);
}

void do_some(std::function<bool(int)> thing)
{
   if (thing(10)) 
   {
      std::cout << "it's true!" << std::endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int local_to_be_modified = 0;
   do_some(
      [&](int in)
      {
         local_to_be_modified = in;
         std::cout << "This is void-" << std::endl;
      }
   );
   do_some(
      [&](int in) -> bool
      { 
         // error: call to 'do_some' is ambiguous
         local_to_be_modified += in;
         std::cout << "This is bool-" << std::endl;
         return true;
      }
   );
}
```

Comment: Because `std::function<void(int)>` can be constructed even from a lambda that returns something (which causes the return value to be ignored).

Comment: As an aside, explicitly specifying the return-type of that lambda does exactly nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the 2nd lambda expression returning `bool` could convert to both `std::function<void(int)>` and `std::function<bool(int)>` implicitly.

[`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) has a converting constructor:

> ```
> template< class F >
> function( F f );
> ```
>
> This constructor does not participate in overload resolution unless f is *[Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function)* for argument types Args... and return type R. (since C++14)

As the definition of [Callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable),

> The following expressions must be valid:
>
> ```
> INVOKE<R>(f, std::declval<ArgTypes>()...)
> ```
>
> where *INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)* is defined as
>   `static_cast<void>(INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN))` if R is possibly
>   cv-qualified `void`, otherwise *INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)*, implicitly
>   converted to R

Note that the 2nd lambda returning `bool`, for the `std::function<void(int)>`, as shown above, `static_cast<void>(INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN))` is a valid expression (the returned `bool` is just converted to `void`). Then it could also convert to `std::function<void(int)>` implicitly and causes the ambiguity issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can explicitly `static_cast` the lambda to the proper type

```
using FunBoolRet = std::function<bool(int)>;

do_some(static_cast<FunBoolRet >([&](int in) 
   {
      local_to_be_modified += in;
      std::cout << "This is bool-" << std::endl;
      return true;
   }));
```

Or store the lambda to the proper `std::function<bool(int)>` type and pass to the function(if `do_some(lmda)` should be called many times)

```
FunBoolRet lmda = [&](int in)
{
    local_to_be_modified += in;
    std::cout << "This is bool-" << std::endl;
    return true;
};    
do_some(lmda); // pass the lambda
```

Or as *@MaxLanghof*  suggested
simply construct `std::function<bool(int)>` from lambda on the go

```
do_some(FunBoolRet{
   [&](int in) 
   {
      local_to_be_modified += in;
      std::cout << "This is bool-" << std::endl;
      return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: You can skip the `static_cast` and just construct a `std::function` directly from it. That's all that happens during implicit conversion anyway.

Comment: My point is that you can literally just remove the `static_cast<` and last `>` and it will do the same thing but with less typing. It doesn't need more lines or anything. https://godbolt.org/z/fQTqF4